# stop lights on passenger vehicles - how many?

Tags: car, brake-light

Not counting the third, central light or any additions that are non standard.

Most vehicles have two lamps, one on each side on the rear. Some have four lamps, two on each side. Are there any cars with a standard of six or more rear brake lamps ?

For these cars having LEDs or something else, equate one lamp to 2A (amperes) of load.

Comment: It really depends on what you mean by "more". Most brake lights these days are made out of multiple small LEDs which blend together as one continuous light when seen from far enough away. I previously had an '08 Hyundai Azera where there were probably 40+ or so LEDs for each side's brake lights (don't know for sure as I never counted them). Needless to say, there are plenty of examples out there, so it really depends on what you mean by your question.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Just edited.

Comment: This seems very much like an [XY issue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). What actual problem are you trying to solve?